# How do you read a database table and display it in a textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

I am creating a basic app for adding and displaying customer information using windows forms in visual studio. i have set it up so i am able to display the contents of the database in a gridview and also add to the database which you can see the code for below. what i am stuck on at the moment is updating the customers information. I want to search the database by customerID which will be entered by the user in a textbox, and display that specific customers details into their relevent textboxes which i can then edit and save.

```
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    // adds customers details to the database
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO customer (title, " + "firstname, " + "lastname, " + "dob, " + "nicode, " + "email, " + "password, " + "allowance) VALUES (@setTitle, @setFirstname, @setLastname, @setDOB, @setNICode, @setEmail, @setPassword, @setAllowance)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("setTitle", cb_title.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("setFirstname", txtFirst_Name.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("setLastname", txtSurname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("setDOB", dtp_DOB.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("setNICode", txtNI_Code.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("setEmail", txtEmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("setPassword", txtPassword.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("setAllowance", txtAllowance.Text);

    int recordsChanged = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Customer Added");
    conn.Close();

    Customers customers = new Customers();
    customers.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

That's what I have for adding a new customer which works fine

```
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    // adds customers details to the database
    cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE customer SET (title, " + "firstname, " + "lastname, " + "dob, " + "nicode, " + "email, " + "password, " + "allowance) VALUES (@setTitle, @setFirstname, @setLastname, @setDOB, @setNICode, @setEmail, @setPassword, @setAllowance)  WHERE custid = @recd";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("title", cb_title_update.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstname", txtFirst_Name_update.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastname", txtSurname_update.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dob", dtp_DOB_update.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nicode", txtNI_Code_update.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", txtEmail_update.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", txtPassword_update.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("allowance", txtAllowance_update.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("recd", Convert.ToInt32(txtSearch.Text));

    int recordsChanged = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Customer Updated");
    conn.Close();

    Customers customers = new Customers();
    customers.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

And that's the code I have so far for updating the database, but I can not figure out how to retrieve the customer data and display it into the textboxes, any help or guidance would be appreciated

Comment: Use a SELECT query instead of a INSERT/UPDATE.  See https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-select/.  Instead of cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() you will use cmd.ExecuteQuery()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Update statement is not correct. Try the following.

```
    cmd.CommandText =@"UPDATE customer 
                    SET title = @setTitle,
                    firstname = @setFirstname, 
                    lastname = @setLastname 
                    dob = @setDOB, 
                    nicode = @setNICode, 
                    email = @setEmail,
                    password = @setPassword, 
                    allowance = @setAllowance 
                    WHERE custid = @recd";
```

It is a bit different from an Insert. Each field is set to a new value. You don't need all that concatenation. This is a literal string.

Of course, in a real application you would **NEVER** store passwords as plain text.

Comment: Thanks will take look, can you suggest how id take value put of a certain colum from a certain row and display that?

Comment: @AdrianRowlands I am not sure what you are asking. Sorry for late reply, I have been very busy lately and we have been without internet or power when Texas was hit by an ice storm.

Comment: Ah not great then lol, no worries I sorted it in the end

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of a certain column from a certain row, you can try to call method [`SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

Here assume you want to get the the customer password.

```
string connectionstring = @"connectin string";

private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from customer where customerID = @cusID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusID", textBoxID.Text);

        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    //  get password column value
                    textBoxPWD.Text = reader["password"].ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("no such record");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nError:\n{0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

As to update the record,

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE customer SET password = @cusPWD WHERE customerID = @cusID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusID", textBoxID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusPWD", textBoxPWD.Text);
        conn.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```